# How can i add a hyperlink to just a part of my jpg image

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I have a jpg image which will have two clickable link
The **food Menu** and the **Beverage Menu**.
How can i add a hyperlink to the two of them respectively.
Many thanks

[image]

EDIT: Any way to make it work for responsive images as well?

Comment: Easiest way is to add an an overlay. This gives a nice example - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [image map](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" usemap="#mymap">

<map name="mymap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="1498,1596,1142,1510" href="foo.htm" alt="Foo">
  <area shape="rect" coords="2092,1596,1636,1510" href="bar.htm" alt="Bar">
</map>
```

Coordinates in above example are very eyeballed.

Comment: cant seems to find the clickable area, any idea?

Comment: let me try again

Comment: quick question, how about for a responsive image that its size changes ?

Comment: You did see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnn5f.png)?? Comments are not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Coords you mean X & Y?
You can do this in Photoshop. Open the image > Right click CROP tool > Choose Slice
Slice the part where you want to create a hyperlink. Once sliced, right clicked the slice, choose Edit Slice. Your X &Y coordinate will show. [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2xit.png)